# Best book for Solving Pdes with Matlab

Tags: partial-differential-equations

I begin to study Pdes and i want to learn how to solve numerically with MatLab.Can you suggest me a "good" book ?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

An excellent book is "Spectral methods in Matlab" by Llyod Trefethen, not specialized in PDEs, but full of useful basic methods. https://people.maths.ox.ac.uk/trefethen/spectral.html

Comment: Thank you very much